Inaccurate group pace
My question here comes from the perspective of a no draft Triathlete.
There are few local riding groups and I notice inaccuracies in describing the average pace.  For example they may ask you to choose between the A group (30-25 mph), B group (25-22) and C group (22 to 18) all in MPH.  The A and B groups tend to be drop groups thinking you can join the lower group if needed and they are all following the same route.
What I have notice is that the A group rarely even reaches 25mph, the B group 22mph, and the C group is usually hovering around 16mph.  When the reality is the average pace should be right in the middle of the stated range and the top pace should be hit frequently.
I've experienced several instances of this with different groups.  Its kind of like online dating where, saying your 6 foot tall means you are really 5' 9".
Is this common in other locations other than Florida?  How much should I overestimate my group speed?
I ask this because I would really like to do the Seattle to Portland ride (~220 miles) and do it in one day.  I would need to be part of a pace group to go that fast that long, and would have to hook up with a group shortly before the race.

Are you really sure the group is advertised as 25-30 mph?  That's 40-55km/h.  If you have a group riding at that pace range they should be professionals, not recreational riders.  I'm reasonably sure you're mixing units here.

A guess: they might have in the past experienced problems with overconfident riders who joined a fast group and then everybody needed to wait for them (would be rude to drop a newbie). It's less risky to advertise each group as faster than it actually is - the worst that can happen is that the newbie gets bored, but then she can always break out ahead of the pack.

Very often, people don't use language precisely unless it's something like a high-stakes situation and/or there are a lot of rules. This would seem to be one example of that fact, possibly assisted by people being optimistic about their capabilities.
Basically, if you're posting a ride, don't overstate your speed. Check your Strava and give a range of typical average speeds. Some clubs may give a range of typical moving speeds on the road (e.g. average 16mph, rolling speed from 15-20mph - I don't think there's standard terminology for this).
Florida is flat, which obviously boosts the average speed, but there's a limit. 25-30mph is professional racing pace.
In common use, clubs don't always use the same scale. E.g. the A grade of the Potomac Pedalers Touring Club is quite fast, but not fast for serious racers - but that club has "Touring" in its name, so you'd expect this. Generally, people would understand a C group as casual pace and distance, suitable for many new riders. An average of 16mph sounds about there. A group that actually averaged 18-22 would typically be regarded as one step above that. I used to do a ride in Baltimore that would average about 19, but it was hilly enough that this was really no joke.

Really I think this is just a units problem, nothing like this.

The OP implied that this was in Florida, so I'm going to assume they were thinking in mph.

In my club, the speed range is rarely reached as well (they give one speed though). I understood the speed is in fact representative of an relatively easy route without too much wind, but the team leaders who have a power meter actually target an average power (for themselves), which should ideally match that average speed in these easy conditions. However routes are often harder than that easy ideal route - or there’s wind. So the announced speed represents rather an ideal - deviations are however not bigger than 2kph average.
